# Multilingual websites using PHP and XML

Tags: php, xml, internationalization

I was asked to create a multilingual website in both English and Arabic languages and i have looked over the internet for samples or demos and didn't find yet i have found those ways,

1. Create a directory for each one (Which i really didn't like)
2. Use XML
3. use MySQL(Which i also don't think it's efficient)
4. And of course the create the PHP array way(but i really didn't like it either)

But i heard that XML is the best approach so what i am asking for is a simple demo for that if anybody have an idea how to create it

Comment: `Zend_Translate` provides a backend with a standardized XML format for translations (Xliff). Total overkill, but if that's what you want...

Comment: What i want is to be able to display the web page in 2 or more languages using XML so i need a simple example for this

Comment: Something like `<text>English</text><translation>近义词</translation>`? Else please concretise your tech buzzword usage and tutoring request. Zend_Translate is documented, and examples easy to google.

Comment: something like that :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<translations>
    <translation id="title">
        <english>Hello there, how are you?</english>
        <italian>Ciao, come stai?</italian>
    </translation>
</translations>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a CMS will be appropriate for this project of yours. A good, light-weight CMS that can handle multi-lingual websites really well is [GetSimple CMS](http://get-simple.info/) with the [I18N plugin](http://get-simple.info/extend/plugin/i18n/69/) installed.

The CMS stores the data in XML files so no MySQL database or similar is required.

Comment: About this CMS i downloaded it but didn't find any XML files in it

Comment: @MohamedHassan: You don't edit the XML files directly, they are created when you create new "pages" for your website via the CMS interface.

Answer (score 1):

hmm i think you need to read this: http://php.net/gettext